# Close votes count on /tools page wrong

Tags: discussion, bug, 10k

Does this happen to anyone else?
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Same here (at least for that example question).

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The page only generates stats for the time range you selected, so if those votes were just from today, you'll only see 2. In fact, [selecting 30d](https://superuser.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days) won't show the question anymore because there are so many other questions with pending 4 close votes.

I could be wrong though.

Comment: Sounds plausible

Comment: Interesting -- this'll make questions with multiple votes distributed over a long time not stand out a lot.

Comment: @DanielBeck True… I wonder what's the official response here. The `/tools` grouping has always got me a bit confused.

Comment: Hopefully someone in the know comes along and either confirms your assumption or refutes it.